# Tomcat Security Permission Error

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm new java Developer and using Mac , tomcat server and NetBeans8.2. I have download tomcat from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi core tar.gz file and place it in my Applications when I start Tomcat from terminal and hit from browser it gives me Error

```
"HTTP Status 500 - access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.jasper")"
```

I have change port number from 8080 to 9999. Please view Attached Image.

Same Issue I'm facing in IDE NetBeans8.2
I have test tomcat7 and tomcat8 but I'm facing Permission issue in both.
How Can I Solve It?

[Permission Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVOPU.png)

Thanks

Comment: What do you use to start tomcat? Looks like you're running within a security manager.

Comment: nothing special i'm running tomcat on Terminal using command first change Directory cd: Applications/tomcat/bin and than run command ./startup.sh. Terminal return this message 

"Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Applications/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Applications/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Applications/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Applications/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Applications/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started."
But when Browser showing same Message

Answer (score -1):

Does `startup.sh` have execute permissions?

Type:

> ls -l

from Tomcat's bin directory. You should see the permissions for all the files within.

To give the file execute permissions, type:

> chmod 700 startup.sh

That gives the owner of the file read,write, and execute permission for that script.

For more details [See here](https://coderanch.com/t/84705/Tomcat-startup-sh-Permission-Denied)

Comment: With that screenshot, tomcat is running already - e.g. OP managed to get it going, no matter what the permissions on this file are

Comment: startup.sh also showing same message on terminal which mention in screenshoot. If port is already busy than i have kill that prosess and start tomcat again and face same message.